# Is it possible to have a fastcgi_cache_path for each website / virtual host?

Tags: nginx, mod-fastcgi

I am using the following config on my http block on nginx.conf:

```
fastcgi_cache_path /var/www/nginx_cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=NGINXCACHE:500m inactive=60m;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500;
```

This works for all websites hosted on this nginx server. I would like to know if it is possible to have each website cache files stored under a specific folder, something like:

- /tmpfs/fastcgi_cache/website1
- /tmpfs/fastcgi_cache/website2

When I daclare multiple fastcgi_cache_path's nginx start gives me a error, even with different zones.

Best regards.

Comment: What did the error say?

Comment: nginx: [emerg] "fastcgi_cache_key" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:38

Comment: **[Y U NO READ DOX???](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFastcgiModule#fastcgi_cache_path)** / fastcgi_cache_path -> Context: http

Comment: Sorry, I have read the docs if that is what it is supposed to mean. Maybe I am missing something, but I think there is no reference to keeping each website cache files under a specific folder. I have not developed purging capabilities to my websites yet, and clients rarely update them, but they do.
My only resource to purge the cache is deleting all the folders content, and I would like to do that on a website basis and not delete all cache files for all websites running under this nginx.
Maybe I am missing something obvious, if that is the case can you please point it out to me?

Comment: no, you read it correct; you can have just one global fastcgi_cache_path, in opposite to proxy_cache where you can define multiple locations for multiple sites. you might find a workaround  with [fastcgi_store](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFastcgiModule#fastcgi_store), but from the docs: `To be clear fastcgi_store is not a cache, it's rather mirror on demand.`

Comment: In fact, you don't need a separate caching pool UNLESS you need a special and different settings for them, i.e. expiration and size. Let me explain why. First to be said, all the cached items are keeping full URL binding, so there's no multi-vhost problem in existance at all! Second, but not so straightforward to discover - it's a bit faster to have one cache rather than two, and a difference is abit disputable, but one cache almost x1.5 faster than four caches. Even when I've put the caches in tmpfs, so I guess that it's an internal NGinx mechanics

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can define multiple cache paths in the nginx `http` context:

```
fastcgi_cache_path /var/run/nginx/cache/site1 levels=1:2 keys_zone=SITE1:100m inactive=1w;
fastcgi_cache_path /var/run/nginx/cache/site2 levels= keys_zone=SITE2:123m inactive=60m;
# other fastcgi_cache_* settings here or in your servers/locations

server {
    server_name site1.com;
    # blablabla

    location ~ \.bla$ {
        # blablabla
        fastcgi_cache SITE1;
    }
}

server {
    server_name site2.com;
    # blablabla

    location ~ \.bla$ {
        # blablabla
        fastcgi_cache SITE2;
    }
}
```

My nginx:

```
nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.1.19
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments:
--prefix=/etc/nginx
--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log
--http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body
--http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log
--http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy
--http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi
--http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi
--lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock
--pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid
--with-debug
--with-http_addition_module
--with-http_dav_module
--with-http_geoip_module
--with-http_gzip_static_module
--with-http_image_filter_module
--with-http_realip_module
--with-http_stub_status_module
--with-http_ssl_module
--with-http_sub_module
--with-http_xslt_module
--with-ipv6
--with-sha1=/usr/include/openssl
--with-md5=/usr/include/openssl
--with-mail
--with-mail_ssl_module
--add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam
--add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-echo
--add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair
--add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module
```

Answer (score 6):

For anybody that followed https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-fastcgi-caching-with-nginx-on-your-vps and is having issues setting up caching for multiple sites and is getting the error `nginx: [emerg] "fastcgi_cache_key" directive is duplicate`.

My solution was to place the `fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";` within /etc/nginx/nginx.conf. As opposed to putting it in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/vhost config which the above tutorial alludes to.

Hope this helps anybody else having a similar issue to me.

Comment: That is exactly what the existing answer advises to do.